# uniting lists out of the googleways package for google directions?

Tags: json, r, google-maps, mapply, googleway

I'm working on looping through long and latitude points for the googleways api. I've come up with two ways to do that in an effort to access the points sections shown in the following link:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/vignettes/googleway-vignette.html

Unforuntaely since this uses a unique key I can't provide a reproducible example but Below are my attempts, one using mapply and the other with a loop. Both work in producing a response in list format, however I am not sure how to unpack it to pull out the points route as you would when passing only one point:

```
df$routes$overview_polyline$points
```

Any suggestions?

```
library(googleway)

dir_results = mapply(
  myfunction,
  origin = feed$origin,
  destination = feed$destination,
  departure = feed$departure
)

OR

empty_df = NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(feed)) {
  print(i)
  output = google_directions(feed[i,"origin"], 
                             feed[i,"destination"], 
                             mode = c("driving"), 
                    departure_time = feed[i,"departure"], 
                    arrival_time = NULL,
                    waypoints = NULL, alternatives = FALSE, avoid = NULL,
                    units = c("metric"), key = chi_directions, simplify = T)
  empty_df = rbind(empty_df, output)
}
```

EDIT**

The intended output would be a data frame like below: where "id" represents the original trip fed in.

```
     lat       lon                                                                    id
1  40.71938 -73.99323 40.7193908691406+-73.9932174682617 40.7096214294434+-73.9497909545898
2  40.71992 -73.99292 40.7193908691406+-73.9932174682617 40.7096214294434+-73.9497909545898
3  40.71984 -73.99266 40.7193908691406+-73.9932174682617 40.7096214294434+-73.9497909545898
4  40.71932 -73.99095 40.7193908691406+-73.9932174682617 40.7096214294434+-73.9497909545898
5  40.71896 -73.98981 40.7193908691406+-73.9932174682617 40.7096214294434+-73.9497909545898
6  40.71824 -73.98745 40.7193908691406+-73.9932174682617 40.7096214294434+-73.9497909545898
7  40.71799 -73.98674 40.7193908691406+-73.9932174682617 40.7096214294434+-73.9497909545898
8  40.71763 -73.98582 40.7193908691406+-73.9932174682617 40.7096214294434+-73.9497909545898
```

EDIT****
dput provided for answering question on dataframe to pair list:

```
structure(list(origin = c("40.7193908691406 -73.9932174682617", 
"40.7641792297363 -73.9734268188477", "40.7507591247559 -73.9739990234375"
), destination = c("40.7096214294434-73.9497909545898", "40.7707366943359-73.9031448364258", 
"40.7711143493652-73.9871368408203")), .Names = c("origin", "destination"
), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

sql code is basic looks like such:

```
feed = sqlQuery(con, paste("select top 10
                             longitude as px,
                             latitude as py,
                             dlongitude as dx ,
                             dlatitude as dy,
                             from mydb"))
```

and then before feeding it my data frame feed looks like so (u can ignore departure i was using that for the distance api):

```
                origin                       destination           departure
1  40.7439613342285 -73.9958724975586  40.716911315918-74.0121383666992 2017-03-03 01:00:32
2  40.7990493774414 -73.9685516357422 40.8066520690918-73.9610137939453 2017-03-03 01:00:33
3  40.7406234741211 -74.0055618286133 40.7496566772461-73.9834671020508 2017-03-03 01:00:33
4  40.7172813415527 -73.9953765869141 40.7503852844238-73.9811019897461 2017-03-03 01:00:33
5  40.7603607177734 -73.9817123413086 40.7416114807129-73.9795761108398 2017-03-03 01:00:34
```

Comment: Added an edit with the intended output

Comment: and are the coordinates all the points in the polyline?

Comment: exactly so the lat lon represents the points in polyline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know the result of the API query returns a list. And if you're doing multiple calls to the API you'll return multiple lists.

So to extract the data of interest you have to do standard operations on lists. In this example it can be done with a couple of `*apply`s

Using the data.frame `feed` where each row consists of an origin lat/lon (`px`/`py`) and a destination lat/lon (`dx`/`dy`)

```
feed <- data.frame(px = c(40.7193, 40.7641),
                   py = c(-73.993, -73.973),
                   dx = c(40.7096, 40.7707),
                   dy = c(-73.949, -73.903))
```

You can use an `apply` to query the `google_directions()` API for each row of the data.frame. And within the same `apply` you can do whatever you want with the result to extract/format it how you want.

```
lst <- apply(feed, 1, function(x){
    ## query Google Directions API
    res <- google_directions(key = key, 
                             origin = c(x[['px']], x[['py']]),
                             destination = c(x[['dx']], x[['dy']]))

    ## Decode the polyline
    df_route <- decode_pl(res$routes$overview_polyline$points)

    ## append the original coordinates as an 'id' column
    df_route[, "id"] <- paste0(paste(x[['px']], x[['py']], sep = "+")
                                ," "
                                , paste(x[['dx']], x[['dy']], sep = "+")
                                , collapse = " ")

    ## store the results of the query, the decoded polyline, 
    ## and the original query coordinates in a list
    lst_result <- list(route = df_route, 
                       full_result = res, 
                       origin = c(x[['px']], x[['py']]), 
                       destination = c(x[['dx']],x[['dy']]))

    return(lst_result)

})
```

So now `lst` is a list that contains the result of each query, plus the decoded polyline as a data.frame. To get all the decoded polylines as a single data.frame you can do another `lapply`, and then `rbind` it all together

```
## do what we want with the result, for example bind all the route coordinates into one data.frame
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, function(x) x[['route']]))
head(df)
       lat       lon                              id
1 40.71938 -73.99323 40.7193+-73.993 40.7096+-73.949
2 40.71992 -73.99292 40.7193+-73.993 40.7096+-73.949
3 40.71984 -73.99266 40.7193+-73.993 40.7096+-73.949
4 40.71932 -73.99095 40.7193+-73.993 40.7096+-73.949
5 40.71896 -73.98981 40.7193+-73.993 40.7096+-73.949
6 40.71824 -73.98745 40.7193+-73.993 40.7096+-73.949
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. Assuming a dataframe named "feed" with two columns, namely "origin" and "destination", how would I change that into a pair list as you have it? I tried pairlist() and setNames(as.list(feed$origin), feed$destination), but neither gave me the name output as yours and I'm new to working with lists. I've included the dput in edits above.

Comment: how do you generate the `feed` data.frame? It might be easier to change how it's created, rather than change it in its current state (as you have to separate each value into it's component lat/lon cooridnates)

Comment: Gotcha, well in my setup I'm pulling these coordinates from a 
sql data base as two columns so they default to a dataframe. 
Any suggestions for pulling to start with a list as you did? You mention you where using a list:
 "Using the data set feed (here I'm using a list of origin/destination pairs)"

Comment: A dataframw is fine to work with, however, in the database are the latitude and longitude values in the same colum? (they shouldn't be)

Comment: No they aren't in the same column. So then what I did was paste them together as pairs like so: -37.84317 144.93818. I do this for both origin and destination.  Added another edit to show the dataframe

Comment: ok - you shouldn't paste them together: i'll update my answer with a `data.frame` solution

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help

Comment: try it now - I've used the column names you've specified in your SQL query

Comment: awesome, i got the results you got, but I did notice that the function only runs the first line of the data frame. How do I output both rows of the data frame?

Comment: @LoF10 what do you mean by `output both rows of the data frame` ?

Comment: I mean output directions for both trips in the data frame feed. The data frame feed has two rows which designate two different trips as far as I understand it. However when you run your function it outputs the route directions for only the first route. Is there a way to use that function to extract routes for both route 1 and route 2. Thanks!

Comment: @LoF10 both results **are** there. Look at `lst[[1]]` and `lst[[2]]`.

Comment: my mistake, i meant when running do.call to turn into a data frame. Works well thank you

Comment: @LoF10 glad it's all sorted :)